# What's the difference between getA() and this.getA()?

Tags: java

Assume that there is a class like the following.

```
public Class SomeClass {
    private A getA() {
        ...
    }

    public void show() {
        A a = getA();    // CASE #1
        ...
    }

    public void show2() {
        A a = this.getA();    // CASE #2
        ...
    }
```

Their result are same, isn't? My idiot co-worker insisted that's right!!(it means they're different.)

Comment: I don't get this. He's an idiot for agreeing with you? He may be an idiot for other reasons but not for this reason.

Comment: They're the same. I have no idea why people add `this` in front of method invocations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same in this context. I'd advocate not using `this` since it's implied and it's just cluttering up the code by being there, but it makes no practical difference whether it's there or not.

It's not useless though. The `this` keyword is required sometimes, for instance:

- When a local variable / parameter hides a field it's used to differentiate between them
- When referring to the outer instance of a class from the inner instance (use Outer.this)
- When using explicit generic types to call a method rather than just infered types (you can't just do `<String, String>stringMethod()`, it has to be `this.<String, String>stringMethod()`.

That's by no means an exhaustive list, just serves as an example to demonstrate while it doesn't make a difference in this case, it can do in other cases!

Answer (score 3):

Your co-worker isn't that much of an idiot after all, because they *are* the same. In the first case, Java implicitly implies `this`.

Answer (score 2):

I will cite the best example of this pointer I came across in my school days.

```
class ThisChk
{
    int param1;
    public int check(int param1)
    {
        this.param1 = param1; //this.param1 is the class variable param1, param1 is the function parameter with a local scope
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a case where you may want to use 'this' just to be clear.

```
class Outer {
     A a;

     public A getA() {
         return a;
     }

     class InnerSuper {
          A a;

          public A getA() {
              return a;
          }
     }

     class Inner extends InnerSuper {
         public void test() {
             A a = Outer.this.getA();
             A a = this.getA();
         }
     }
}
```